# What rights does an account require to log on as a batch job?

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, veritas-cluster-server

I've got a Windows batch script which I'm trying to get Veritas Cluster Server to control using the process agent.

The batch script needs to run as a particular user, but when I try to online the resource I get the following error in the event log:

```
Source: AgentFramework

Event ID: 6532

Process:<<resource name>> Failed to launch the program <<path to batch script>>. Error = 1385
```

When I look up that error code here, it shows as:

```
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.
```

So the user account in question can't log on. That user account already runs some services, and has been granted the Logon as a service right. I've also added the Log on as a batch job right, but the problem persists.

So what rights do I need to assign to that account so that VCS can start a batch script as that user?

The operating system is Windows Server 2003, and VCS is version 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Open your `Administrative Tools` > `Local Security Policy`. Under `Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment` > Make sure your user is set to `Log on as a batch job`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rights on `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` - make sure the user has `Execute` permissions.